# datatable jQuery row selection value output

Tags: jquery, datatables

The code below is designed to search in a table. I'm using datatable jQuery and I'm trying to minimize the number of imported records by searching before using the built in filtering feature.

My problem starts with the second search onwards. you can see from the attached image that select function fires proportionally with the number function calls.
 Any idea why?

```
function srctbl() {
    $("#RegSrc").dataTable().fnDestroy();
    var RegSrctbl = $('#RegSrc').DataTable({
        select: true,
        scrollY: 200,
        deferRender: true,
        scroller: true,
        rowId: 'Filenum',
        //"processing": false,
        //"serverSide": false,
        "ajax": {
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "../CONFIG/WebSerTblsSearch.asmx/SrcTblReg",
            type: "Post",
            data: function (dtParms) {
                return JSON.stringify({
                    SrchTxt: $('#srctxt').val(),
                    FnameSrctxt: $('#fnamesrc').val(),
                    SnameSrctxt: $('#snamesrc').val(),
                    TnameSrctxt: $('#tnamesrc').val(),
                    LnameSrctxt: $('#lnamesrc').val(),
                    TelSrcTxt: $('#telsrc').val(),
                    SSNSrcTxt: $('#ssnsrc').val(),
                    EmailSrctxt: $('#emailsrc').val(),
                    DOBSrcTxt: $('#dobsrc').val()
                });
            },
            dataFilter: function (res) {
                var parsed = JSON.parse(res);
                var morp = JSON.parse(parsed.d);
                return JSON.stringify({ data: morp });
            },
            error: function (x, y) {
                console.log(x);
            }
        },
        deferRender: true,
        columns: [
            { data: "Filenum" },
            { data: "FullName" },
            { data: "DOB" }
        ],
        select: {
            style: 'single',
            blurable: true
        },
    });
    $("#RegSrc").on("click", "tr", function () {
        console.log($(this).children(":first").text());
        $("#trgtval").val(($(this).children(":first").text()))
    });
}
```

`console.log()` showing number of event fires with each selection after the first function call

[image: console log showing number of event fires with each selection after the first function call]

Comment: try $("#RegSrc").off('click').on("click", ....

Comment: did not work, sorry

Comment: srctbl() is bound to a button click function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that the `click` event handler attached to *static* element is registered within a scope of a function which is called more than once.
Basically a single click on a `tr` element will fire as many times, as many times the `srctbl()` was called.

Even you register `click` for dynamically created `tr` elements, You're attaching that event to the `#RegSrc` table - it's an [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Move click event handler outside:

```
function srctbl() {
    //...
}

$("#RegSrc").on("click", "tr", function () {
    console.log($(this).children(":first").text());
    $("#trgtval").val(($(this).children(":first").text()))
});
```